# Sveltekit static app deployed to Vercel gives 404 error when reloading sub routes

Tags: vercel, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-static

I built my Sveltekit application using `adapter-static`.

Everything works fine locally in my development environment, I can reload sub routes and still get the correct page content.

When deploying to Vercel, I can't reload or go to a sub route page without first going to the index page and navigating to it anymore, as I am prompted with a 404 error.

I tried adding a `vercel.json` file at the root of my project :

```json
{
    "rewrites": [
        {"source": "/(.*)", "destination": "/"}
    ]
}
```

But this doesn't work as this is for the react router (I think).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix my issue.

## Solution 1 : redirect all routes to their .html equivalent

This is needed because Sveltekit generates sub route pages as for example a `sub-route.html` file, whereas Vercel seems to be looking for a `sub-route/index.html` file.

Add a `vercel.json` file located at the root of the project :

```json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)/?$",
      "dest": "/$1.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

This will redirect :

- `/my-route` -> `/my-route.html`
- `/my/sub-route` -> `/my/sub-route.html`

But this will **NOT** redirect routes with trailing slashes :

- `/my-route/` -> ERROR 404
- `/my/sub-route/` -> ERROR 404

## Solution 2 : trailingSlash = 'always'

I had defined a `+layout.ts` file at the root of all routes for my static app, and I added this :

```js
export const prerender = true;
export const trailingSlash = 'always'; // Added this
```

This forces Sveltekit to generate sub route pages as `sub-route/index.html` files, and adds a trailing slash to every route.